How can I add an IPreferenceChangeListener that responds to individual preference change?
I would like to add a listener that will action when general Eclipse preference is changed.
I know how to do this for a specific preference page using the Activator of the UI plugin that declares the page. You might use the following API called from the Activator.start() method:
But I would like to notify when preference is changed, I tried the following code in Activator.start() method
Also some time this is called but it is calling multiple times so how to avoid multiple calling and make it single call.
private IPreferenceChangeListener fPreferenceChangeListener;
    private void addPreferenceChangeListeners() throws BackingStoreException {
        
        fPreferenceChangeListener = new IPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void preferenceChange(PreferenceChangeEvent event) {
               System.out.println("Hello");
        };

        IPreferencesService prefsService = Platform.getPreferencesService();
        IEclipsePreferences root = prefsService.getRootNode();

        /*
         * Create a visitor for adding the pref change listener to each node.
         */
        IPreferenceNodeVisitor addingVisitor = new IPreferenceNodeVisitor() {
            @Override
            public boolean visit(IEclipsePreferences node) throws BackingStoreException {
                if(null!=fPreferenceChangeListener) {
                    node.addPreferenceChangeListener(fPreferenceChangeListener);
                    node.addNodeChangeListener(new INodeChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void removed(NodeChangeEvent event) {
                            //
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void added(NodeChangeEvent event) {
                            IEclipsePreferences node = (IEclipsePreferences) event.getChild();
                            node.addPreferenceChangeListener(fPreferenceChangeListener);
                        }
                    });
                }
                return true;
            }
        };

        /*
         * Add the listener to the root and all its children
         */
        try {
            root.accept(addingVisitor);
        } catch (BackingStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


You might have a look how the Oomph Preference Recorder does it: https://github.com/eclipse-oomph/oomph/blob/master/plugins/org.eclipse.oomph.preferences/src/org/eclipse/oomph/preferences/util/PreferencesRecorder.java

You can add a listener to a specific node, but you can't listen for just a particular key. However if you have an e4 injected part you can use the @Preference annotation to get changes to a key (see for this tutorial)
